# Getting all domain controller in the forest using WMI

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi, wmic

I am using the following WMI query against a DC in order to get all the dc's in the forest:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\directory\ldap -Class ds_computer |
    Where-Object {$_.ds_useraccountcontrol -eq 532480} | select DS_dNSHostName
```

I have a single domain in my forest. I wonder if in case of multiple domains in the forest, the above query against a single DC will provide my a list of all the DC's in the forest. if not, I would appreciate if someone can provide me a different query that does.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with WMI? Would LDAP work for you?

Comment: LDAP can also work, TNX

Comment: Why not just `(Get-ADDomainController -Filter *).HostName` or for the forest: `(Get-ADForest).Domains | %{ Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_ } | Select HostName`

Comment: Hi I can use only LDAP or WMI, I cannot run in this environment POWERSHELL